# Solicitações HTTP em C++

Tags: c++, json, http

Como eu poderia fazer uma solicitação em uma URL que retornaria um jSON em C++?

Preciso acessar uma URL /return.php que retorna a string

```
{"status":true,"hash":"12#87!!3@WSS\/.","user":"admin"}
```

e trabalhar ela em meu projeto, acessando o json como obj.status por exemplo.

Comment: Ao tentar responder à pergunta, percebi que "fazer uma requisição HTTP" e "interpretar um JSON" são duas etapas suficientemente distintas que mereciam cada uma uma pergunta separada. De todo modo, deixei minha resposta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

De acordo com [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1011339/520779), o modo de fazer uma requisição HTTP depende do sistema operacional e/ou do uso de bibliotecas externas. Segundo a resposta aceita, a forma recomendada é através da biblioteca [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), usando [um dos seus *bindings* pra C++](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/cplusplus/). [Essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112084/520779) possui um exemplo de código usando o segundo link:

```
// Edit : rewritten for cURLpp 0.7.3
// Note : namespace changed, was cURLpp in 0.7.2 ...
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>

// RAII cleanup
curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;

// standard request object.
curlpp::Easy myRequest;

// Set the URL.
myRequest.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url(std::string("http://www.wikipedia.com")));

// Send request and get a result.
// By default the result goes to standard output.
// Here I use a shortcut to get it in a string stream ...
std::ostringstream os;
os << myRequest.perform();

string asAskedInQuestion = os.str();
```

Embora a princípio seja possível usar o libcurl no Windows também, há uma solução alternativa que usa somente as bibliotecas nativas deste, [nessa outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12374407/520779).

Uma vez feita a requisição HTTP e obtida a resposta, basta então interpretar o JSON. A página [json.org](http://json.org/) lista diversas opções de bibliotecas para fazer o *parsing*. É difícil sugerir uma, pois são tantas, e [mesmo no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/245973/520779)* não há uma resposta boa com exemplos, mas eu achei o [RapidJSON](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson) à primeira vista bastante simples de usar:

```
// rapidjson/example/simpledom/simpledom.cpp`
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace rapidjson;

int main() {
    // 1. Parse a JSON string into DOM.
    const char* json = "{\"project\":\"rapidjson\",\"stars\":10}";
    Document d;
    d.Parse(json);

    // 2. Modify it by DOM.
    Value& s = d["stars"];
    s.SetInt(s.GetInt() + 1);

    // 3. Stringify the DOM
    StringBuffer buffer;
    Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
    d.Accept(writer);

    // Output {"project":"rapidjson","stars":11}
    std::cout << buffer.GetString() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

* Nota: link quebrado (a pergunta no SOen, *"What's the best C++ JSON parser?"*, foi removida e só pode ser acessada por quem tem 10 mil pontos de reputação ou mais no SOen)

Comment: Sua resposta é melhor do que qualquer uma que eu havia encontrado no SOEN. Segui sua sugestão e testei o RapidJSON, talvez ainda seja cedo para dizer, mas a princípio está funcionando muito bem para mim. PS: o link da sua resposta para o SOEN está quebrado.

Comment: @Math como acontece muito com alguns usuários aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Você está querendo integrar um sistema composto por códigos em linguagens diferentes.

Uma opção para integração de sistemas legados é o CORBA (Common Object Request Broker Architecture).

Ele é basicamente uma norma para intercomunicação. As diversas linguagens estudam a norma e criam bibliotecas para essa extensão. No caso a extensão de "comunicação via CORBA".

Na época da faculdade, lá por 2004, estudei isso e fiz umas integrações de Java com C; depois acabei não trabalhando mais com isso então não sei se existe algo mais atual.

Vi que existe a extensão para php aqui:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/phporb/

E a extensão para C++ aqui:
http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/

Não sei se são as melhores bibliotecas para isso pois não usei nem testei, mas creio que esse é o caminho que você deve seguir.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi da pergunta, o que o autor quer é abrir um URL a partir do seu código C++, que por acaso está em PHP, mas poderia usar qualquer tecnologia. Ou seja, é uma questão de fazer uma requisição HTTP para um servidor específico, não de integrar duas linguagens (caso em que sua resposta estaria excelente).

Comment: Sim, não tenho a necessidade de integrar duas linguagens mas sim de criar uma via de comunicação entre duas aplicações diferentes.